# What is the proper way to communicate between member classes?

Tags: c++, object

I'm writing an RPG, and the basic code is below. Each player is supposed to have four stats: earth, air, fire, and water. The problem is this: if fire is less than zero, it should spill over into damage to earth. Here is my code so far:

```
//DANCE GAME
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class element {
    public:
        //get primary magnitude
        int gpm(){
            return pm;
        };
        //set primary magnitude
        int spm(int x){
            pm = x;
        };
    protected:
        //primary magnitude
        int pm;
};

class fire : public element {
};

class earth : public element {
};

class soul {
    public:
        earth e;
        fire f;
};

int main () {
    soul p1, p2;

    p1.e.spm(5);
    cout << p1.e.gpm() << endl;

    p1.f.spm(5);
    cout << p1.f.gpm() << endl;

    return 0;
};
```

So, I want each element to have a unique spm() function to control its special behavior. For fire, it should have the effect of the pseudocode below:

```
fire.spm(int x)
    pm += x
    if pm < 0
        x = abs(pm)
        pm = 0
        owner.earth -= x
```

Obviously it's that last line that's giving me problems. What is the proper way to accomplish such a thing?

Comment: You should try to use more descriptive function names. I have no idea what `spm` or `gpm` could mean, and when you look at that code in a few years you will likely not remember either. One-letter variable names are also usually a no-go.

Comment: It's not enough to explain the acronym before defining the function?

Comment: only when you define the acronym again whenever you are *calling* the function. When you try to understand sourcecode, you usually look at the calls, not the definitions. What is more readable when you only look at this one line: `p1.e.spm(5);` or `player1Soul.earthElement.setPrimaryMagnitude(5)`

Comment: I only read this briefly because it made my head hurt a bit and I'm busy, but it seems to me like you are at risk of introducing heavy coupling between all of your components. Do you really want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass owner as argument to method spm.

Comment: I tried this in a previous iteration of my game, and I ended up with a lot of methods that needed to accept 6-8 arguments each.

Comment: In that case you should probably add more classes, that will encapsulate data.

Comment: No, you probably shouldn't (pass owner as argument to spm). This leads to spagetti dependencies (and breaks Law of Demeter).

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously it's that last line that's giving me problems. What is the proper way to accomplish such a thing?

There is a guide line that states that you should not work on another object's data (Law of Demeter). Instead, you should propagate the changes downwards, from objects that know everyone else, to objects that know only how to handle their own data.

This means that your `fire` element implementation should not know that a `soul` has an `earth` element (let alone try to alter it directly). It is instead the responsibility of the `soul` to propagate these changes (because a `soul` instance knows both `earth` and `fire` classes).

Based on this, you should consider something like this:

```
class element
{
public:
    // update primary magnitude, taking hints from the provided element
    // if this->get_type() == other.get_type()
    // at the end of the operation, primary_magnitude_ should be 
    // other.primary_magnitude_;
    virtual void update(const element& other)
    {
        if(get_type() == other.get_type())
            set_magnitude(other.magnitude());
    }
protected:
    enum { earth_type, fire_type, air_type, water_type } element_type;
    virtual element_type get_type() const = 0;

    int magnitude() const { return primary_magnitude_; }
    void update_magnitude(int delta) { primary_magnitude_ += delta; }
    void set_magnitude(int value) { primary_magnitude_ = delta; }

private:

    int primary_magnitude_;
};

class earth
{
public:
    void update(const element& other) override
    {
        switch(other.get_type())
        {
        case element::earth_type:
            set_magnitude(other.magnitude());
            break;
        case element::fire_type:
            update_magnitude( std::min(0, other.magnitude()) );
            break;
        }
    }
protected:
    element_type get_type() const override { return element::earth_type; }
};

class soul
{
public:
    void update(const element& value)
    {
        earth_.update(value);
        fire_.update(value);
    }
private:
    earth earth_;
    fire fire_;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand your code, but I'm not sure I need to. I think "Law of Demeter" is the answer to my question. I googled it and I think I should now be able to construct my program in accordance with those style guidelines.

Comment: The point of my code was to show that a change where the `earth` and `fire` are changed for a `soul`, should be done through a function in the `soul` class (i.e. not a function in `earth` or in `fire`). More than that, if `soul` knows of `earth` and `fire`, then `soul` should tell them to `update` their values (and `earth` and `fire` do not need to know anything about `soul` (or it's data or operations). Basically, the dependency relationship between them is from `soul` to the elements, but not the other way around.

Comment: `soul` updates it's members (and only those), `earth` updates it's members and `fire` updates it's members. Further, none of them know of the members of the others, except `soul` (who knows the public interfaces of it's members).

Comment: If there are to be two instances of soul, p1 and p2, I supposed it is considered LoD-compliant that each should know of the other? For instance, suppose a player is supposed to have a move called strike. How would you implement it so that it modifies the .fire of the other player?

Comment: It is not LoD compliant. I would use something similar to: `void player::add_damage(const attack_data& attack) { soul.update( attack.elemental_damage() ); }` where a `player` has a `soul` member (or is an instance of `soul`), the `update` function is described in my answer, and `attack_data::elemental_damage` returns an `element` instance. The `add_damage` would be called from a fight function/loop, that doesn't belong to any player. In this scenario, a player receives attacks, not other players (and I assume attacks can also come from in-game monsters, traps and what-not).

Answer (score 0):

`spm` means "set primary magnitude". Two notes on this. First, it's better to call function `SetPrimaryMagnitude` or `set_primary_magnitude` if the function is supposed to actually set the primary magnitude. It makes life so much easier. BTW, `element` class has only one value, `pm`, so I don't see the need to call that value "primary". I mean, what would be "secondary"?

Second, you actually don't want to set that value but to have a combination of actions that increase, decrease, and spill the difference to yet another value. Maybe it would be better to call such action "adjust". And make it a member of `soul` (if that class is the only one that handles the math this specific way). Something like this:

```
soul::AdjustElementValues(element& primary, element& secondary, int value)
{
    // decrease primary by value, and if needed spill the remains to secondary
}
```

If `soul` is not the only class that does this math, then move the math to separate class, which has access to all needed objects. Say, `class element_spiller` with constructor that takes pointers to two `elements`, primary and secondary, and has a method that takes `int value` argument and changes the `elements` accordingly.